# How do I handle an error that happens when I use sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, vba, t-sql, ms-access-2016, sql-server-2019

I am running a stored procedure to generate a SQL statement, then using `sp_executesql` to run it. The statement creates a `view` that looks at a linked server. When this view is executed, it throws an error in SSMS:

> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Procedure LINKEDSERVERVIEW, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 8]

> An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT...

This error makes sense to be thrown. The problem, however, is that my calling program is Microsoft Access and this error isn't being passed to Access. My SP executes as if there is nothing wrong. How can I read the result of `sp_executesql` and handle the error myself?

**The SP:**

```
declare @Status = 'OK'
declare @def nvarchar(4000) = 'ALTER VIEW dbo.LINKEDSERVERVIEW AS  SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER2, ''SELECT * FROM COM_INTEGRATION_SHIP'') AS derivedtbl_1  '
begin try
begin tran
  exec sp_executesql @def //Throws an error in SSMS but not in MS Access
commit tran
end try
begin catch
  set @Status = (select error_message())
end catch
```

**VBA:**

```
Function SwitchLinkedServer(strDSN As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrLabel

   Dim strTo As String, con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, prm As New ADODB.Parameter

   SwitchLinkedServer = False

   'convert dsn to linked server name for sp
   strTo = DLookup("LinkedServername", "[#DSN2LinkedServer]", "DSNname = '" & strDSN & "'")
   
   If Not EstablishConnection(con) Then
      ErrHandler glbLastErrNum, glbLastError
      GoTo ExitLabel
   End If

   Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cmd.CommandText = "_SwitchLinkedServer"
   
   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@To", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, strTo)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm
   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Status", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm

   cmd.Execute
 
   If cmd.Parameters("@Status") <> "OK" Then
      MsgBox "ERROR"
      GoTo ExitLabel
   End If

   SwitchLinkedServer = True

ExitLabel:
On Error Resume Next

   Set prm = Nothing
   Set cmd = Nothing
   TerminateConnection con
   Exit Function

ErrLabel:

   ErrHandler Err.Number, Err.Description
   Resume ExitLabel
   
End Function
```

Comment: How do you want to handle the error, though? What should happen inside the SQL Server database, and what should happen inside Access? How are you invoking that procedure from within Access? Are you using VBA? If so, are you using `On Error...`?

Comment: @Dai in the stored procedure I just want to set a variable to something like 'ERROR'. And then in Access, if this variable has 'ERROR' in it, I'll show the user a `MsgBox`.

Comment: @Dai in Access I'm using `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Command` to execute it

Comment: Don't try to build your own error-reporting system, you should use ADODB's built-in support for error-handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/errors-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Dai I'm not trying to, don't worry. I just need to know how to check the result of `sp_executesql` inside my stored procedure.

Comment: `sp_executesql` returns an `int` that's either `0` or `1` - so do `DECLARE @res int; SET @res = EXECUTE sp_executesql @def` - if that doesn't work then use `BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH`.

Comment: @Dai I believe the syntax might be `exec @result = sp_executesql @def`. Yours gives a syntax error. However, even when I did this, the error seems to stop `@result` from being written. I do a simple `select @result` right after `exec @result...` and it doesn't display the result in SSMS, much less the calling program

Comment: Please show us the source-code of the `PROCEDURE` you're executing - and yes, you're right about the syntax for `EXEC @result = sp_executesql...`

Comment: @Dai ok I added the full version of the thing that `sp_executesql` is executing. It `ALTERS` a view to point to a different linked server, that's all.

Comment: maybe this will help:  https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Appendix1.html (Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server,  Appendix 1: Linked Servers).

Comment: @MoeSisko good reading material, I've been looking at it all day. Still haven't found a way to catch the error returned by the remote server, but hopefully the answer is somewhere in there

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the SP _SwitchLinkedServer must include @Status as an Output parameter or it will not update in the calling context, i.e. your VBA function.